# How to use Jekyll-paginate without index.html?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown, jekyll-paginator

I'm trying to build my blog on Github pages and I have to use Jekyll-paginate for obvious reasons. The problem is, I don't use the index.html page for anything other than a welcome page. I have a separate page called index.html in a folder called articles, thus the url for the blog should be `xyz.github.io/articles/`.

However, this presents a major problem - apparently jekyll-paginate refuses to work without an explicit index.html in the root directory of the blog. So, I tried using jekyll-paginate-v2 which has no such restrictions, and it worked perfectly!

However, github pages don't support jekyll-paginate-v2, and thus, I'm back to square 1. What should I do?

**NOTE** : Here's my code:

## index.md

```
---
layout: home
title: SomuSysAdmin
---

If you're new to this site and have no idea what's going on, first go and read the [About](about.md) section of the blog.

Here's a list of all the major articles this blog contains: 

## [Red Hat Certified Systems Administrator (RHCSA) Guide]({% post_url 2017-09-11-RHCSA %})
```

## And here's my _config.yml:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  User configuration
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

title:               SomuSysAdmin

# The unique resource location of your page.
# Set to `https://<username>.github.io` when hosting on GitHub Pages
url:                 https://somuSysAdmin.github.io

# Set to '' when hosting a blog on GitHub Pages, ie on `//<username>.github.io`
# Set to '/<reponame>' when using the `gh-pages` branch of a repository
baseurl:             ''

# A very short description of your page
tagline:             Easiest way to earn some SysAdmin mojo!

# A short description of the page, used in the sidebar and as fallback for the meta description tag.
# Markdown enabled, but don't use more than one paragraph (enforced by `>`)
description:         >
  A short set of notes and pointers concerning everything I know about System Administration.
# This should be the same author as first entry in `_data/authors.yml`
author:
  name:              Somenath Sinha
  email:             somu.sysa_fakeID@gmail.com

# Fallback image and color
image:               /assets/img/nap.jpg
color:               '#4ea97e'

# The font used for headings. Expects a string that is a valid CSS font-family value.
font_heading:        "'Roboto Slab', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"

# The text font. Expects a string that is a valid CSS font-family value.
font:                "'Noto Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"

# The string encoding what fonts to fetch from Google Fonts.
# See: https://qwtel.com/hydejack/docs/configuration/
google_fonts:        Roboto+Slab:700|Noto+Sans:400,400i,700,700i

# If you do not use a Google Fonts, uncomment the line below
# no_google_fonts:     true

# Set your Google Analytics id to receive `pageview` events.
# To remove Google Anaylics from your page, remove the line below.
google_analytics:    <UA-XXXXXXXX-X>

# Setting a disqus shortname will enable the comment section on pages with `comments: true` in the front matter
disqus_shortname:    somusa

# This text will appear in the footer of every page. Markdown enabled.
copyright:           '&copy; 2017 Somenath Sinha. All rights reserved.'

# Format of the permalinks
permalink:           pretty

# Pagination configuration (used by the `blog` layout)
paginate:            5
paginate_path:       '/page-:num/'

# If you are upgrading form a v5 verison of Hydejack, uncomment the two lines below,
# so that the location of the feed XML stays the same.
# feed:
#   path:              atom.xml

# Set to true when building with the `--lsi` option
# See: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#site-variables
# use_lsi:             true

# Set to `true` if you don't want to show an icon after each link that opens to an external site
# no_mark_external:    true

# Uncomment this line if third party plugins fail to work with dynimically loaded pages
# disable_push_state:  true

# Uncomment this line if want to disable the touch drawer on mobile
# disable_drawer: true

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Collections
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

collections:
  featured_categories:
    permalink:       /category/:name/
    output:          true
  featured_tags:
    permalink:       /tag/:name/
    output:          true
  projects:
    permalink:       /projects/:path/
    output:          true

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Advanced configuration
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

gems:
  - jekyll-default-layout
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-optional-front-matter
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-redirect-from
  - jekyll-relative-links
  - jekyll-sitemap

exclude:
  - README.md
  - node_modules
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock

kramdown:
  footnote_backlink: '&#x21a9;&#xfe0e;'
  math_engine:       mathjax
  math_engine_opts:
    preview:         true
    preview_as_code: true

compress_html:
  comments:          ["<!-- ", " -->"]
  clippings:         all
  endings:           all
  ignore:
    envs:            [development]

sass:
  style:             compressed
```

## Here's the content of my articles/index.md:

```
---
layout  : blog
title   : Articles
menu    : true
order   : 1
---
```

So, is there any way I can use jekyll-paginate without using an explicit index.html?

Here's what happens when I try to run jekyll on my present blog without an index.html:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve --incremental
Configuration file: D:/Git/blog/_config.yml
      Deprecation: The 'gems' configuration option has been renamed to 'plugins'. Please update your config file accordingly.
      Source: D:/Git/blog
      Destination: D:/Git/blog/_site
Incremental build: enabled
    Generating...
      Pagination: Pagination is enabled, but I couldn't find an index.html page to use as the pagination template. Skipping pagination.
                    done in 1.736 seconds.
Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'D:/Git/blog'
  Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

As you can see, *the pagination doesn't work **at all!** So, how do I fix it?* I'm new to markdown and jekyll, so I may even be missing something obvious! Please help me fix it!

Comment: Why would you not want an index page? Without one, `xyz.github.io/` returns an error, which would suggest to users that they had misspelled your site. The index page is a landing page and if that doesn't work, people won't bother trying to dig further for the page they want.

Comment: @Waylan Not really - I don't want an explicit index.html page. I already have an `index.md` page, that jekyll converts to `index.html` in the _site folder. I just don't wanna actually put an index.html page in the root folder instead of an index.md page. I just don't wanna use the index.html as a blog page, instead use another articles/index.html page. But even when I point jekyll to `article/index.html` page, it still says that a pagination template (for which it needs the index.html) is missing!

Comment: Wait, you have an `index.md` page? Sorry, I thought you had no index page at all. Of course, Jekyll will convert `index.md` to index.html`, so the final built output will contain an index.html page there. That being the case, ignore my comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation for Jekyll pagination](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/) says:

> **Pagination only works within HTML files**
>
> Pagination does not work from within Markdown or Textile files from your Jekyll site. Pagination works when called from within the HTML file, named `index.html`, which optionally may reside in and produce pagination from within a subdirectory, via the `paginate_path` configuration value.

So if you want your blog to be on URL `/articles/` and `/articles/N/`, specify this in your configuration:

```
paginate_path: "/articles/:num/"
```

And place an `index.html` file inside `articles` directory, which lists the posts for the current page:

```
<!-- This loops through the paginated posts -->
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
  <h1><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
  <p class="author">
    <span class="date">{{ post.date }}</span>
  </p>
  <div class="content">
    {{ post.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}

<!-- Pagination links -->
<div class="pagination">
  {% if paginator.previous_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path }}" class="previous">Previous</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="previous">Previous</span>
  {% endif %}
  <span class="page_number ">Page: {{ paginator.page }} of {{ paginator.total_pages }}</span>
  {% if paginator.next_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path }}" class="next">Next</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="next ">Next</span>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

(See the [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/) for more snippets and configuration details.)

**EDIT:** I think your problem was your `paginate_path` setting. You set it to `'/page-:num/'`, therefore Jekyll Paginate looked for `index.html` in your site root.

Comment: Already solved this, should have provided my ans here-- turns out jekyll parses markdown even inside html files. Thus all I had to do was rename `/index.md` to `/index.html` along with chaning thr pagination path (as you mentioned) to get it all working !! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For me the [solution](https://github.com/sylhare/Type-on-Strap/issues/212) was:

What you need to do, if you want to have your blog page outside of `index.html` completely.

```sh
blog                   # New directory
└── index.html         # Your new blog page
```

In your this `blog/index.html` you need to add this which will render the blog page (the `home` layout is where you have the `paginator.posts`)

```yaml
---
layout: home
title: Blog
permalink: /blog/
---
```

And then make sure you have the paginator config in your `_config.yml` with:

```yaml
# PAGINATION
paginate: 5
paginate_path: "/blog/page:num"
```

Comment: In my case I had to omit the `permalink: /blog/` part